# Query builder update() codeigniter 4 not updateing my password

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4, php-password-hash

i'd like to ask some question. I want to make a change password feature in codeigniter 4, so i have to updateing my old password, but when i do that, the password it's not updated, but all my flashdata works perfectly. I also try a normal sql query but not work too.
Where is my mistake?

When i var_dump the new hash password, the new password is hashed, but again not updating my database.

This is my model

```
protected $user = 'user';

public function EditKataSandi($password_hash = null){
        $session = \Config\Services::session();
        $id = $session->get('id');
        $db      = \Config\Database::connect();
        $builder = $db->table($this->user);
        //$queryB = "UPDATE `user` SET `sandi` = $password_hash WHERE `id` = $id
        //";
        // $menu = $db->query($queryB);
        // return $menu;
        $builder->set('sandi', $password_hash);
        $builder->where('id', $id);
        return $query = $builder->update();
    }
```

my controller

```
protected $helpers = ['form', 'url', 'array'];
    public function katasandi($page = 'katasandi'){
            $request = \Config\Services::request();
            $validation = \Config\Services::validation();
            $model = new Model_all();
            $email = $this->session->get('email');

            if (!$email){
                return redirect()->to(base_url('/auth'));
            }else{
                $userAccess = $model->Tendang();
                if ($userAccess < 1) {
                    return redirect()->to(base_url('/auth/blokir'));
                }
            }

            if (! is_file(APPPATH.'/Views/admin/admin-katasandi/v_katasandi.php'))
            {
                // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                throw new \CodeIgniter\Exceptions\PageNotFoundException($page);
            }

            if($request->getMethod() == 'post'){
                $validation->setRules([
                    'katasandi_sebelum' => [
                        'label'  => 'Kata sandi sebelum',
                        'rules'  => 'required|trim',
                        'errors' => [
                            'required' => 'Harus diisi harus diisi!'

                        ]
                    ],
                    'katasandi_baru' => [
                        'label'  => 'Sandi Baru',
                        'rules'  => 'required|trim|min_length[6]|matches[katasandi_baru1]',
                        'errors' => [
                            'required' => 'Harus diisi!',
                            'matches' => '',
                            'min_length' => 'Terlalu pendek!'
                        ]
                    ],
                    'katasandi_baru1' => [
                        'label'  => 'Sandi Ulangi',
                        'rules'  => 'required|trim|min_length[6]|matches[katasandi_baru]',
                        'errors' => [
                            'required' => 'Harus diisi!',
                            'matches' => 'Harus sesuai dengan kata sandi baru!',
                            'min_length' => ''
                        ]
                    ]
                ]);
            }
                $data['nama'] = $model->GetNama();
                $data['title'] = ucfirst('Ubah Kata Sandi'); // Capitalize the first letter
                $data['user'] = $model->UserLogin();
                $data['menu'] = $model->MenuAll();
                $data['attr'] = ['id' => 'katasandi', 'name'=>'katasandi'];

            if($validation->withRequest($this->request)->run() == FALSE){
                echo view('admin/admin-base-html/v_header', $data);
                echo view('admin/admin-base-html/v_navbar', $data);
                echo view('admin/admin-base-html/v_sidebar');
                echo view('admin/admin-katasandi/v_katasandi', ['validation' => $validation,'session' => $this->session]);
                echo view('admin/admin-base-html/v_footer');
                echo view('admin/admin-base-html/v_js');
                echo view('admin/admin-katasandi/v_js_katasandi');
            }else{
                $pass_sebelum = $request->getPost('katasandi_sebelum');
                $pass_baru = $request->getPost('katasandi_baru');
                if (!password_verify($pass_sebelum, $data['user']['sandi'])) {
                    $this->session->setFlashdata('salah', 'Kata sandi sebelumnya salah!');
                    return redirect()->to(base_url('/pengguna/katasandi'));
                }else{
                    if ($pass_sebelum == $pass_baru) {
                        $this->session->setFlashdata('sama', 'Kata sandi baru tidak boleh sama dengan kata sandi sebelumnya!');
                        return redirect()->to(base_url('/pengguna/katasandi'));
                    }else{
                        $password_hash = password_hash($pass_baru, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                        $model->EditKataSandi($password_hash);
                        $this->session->setFlashdata('pesan', 'Kata sandi berhasil diubah!');
                        return redirect()->to(base_url('/pengguna/katasandi'));
                    }
                }


            }
        }
```

my view

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          <?php echo form_open(base_url().'/pengguna/katasandi', $attr);    ?>
          <?php echo csrf_field(); ?>

            <div class="card card-primary">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h4>Ubah kata sandi</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <label for="katasandi_sebelum">Kata sandi sebelumnya</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="katasandi_sebelum" name="katasandi_sebelum"
                      placeholder="" autofocus>
                      <label class="text-danger"><?php echo $validation->showError('katasandi_sebelum') ?></label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                    <label for="katasandi_baru">Kata sandi baru</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="katasandi_baru" name="katasandi_baru" placeholder="">
                    <label class="text-danger"><?php echo $validation->showError('katasandi_baru') ?></label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                    <label for="katasandi_baru1">Ulangi kata sandi baru</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="katasandi_baru1" name="katasandi_baru1"
                      placeholder="">
                    <label class="text-danger"><?php echo $validation->showError('katasandi_baru1')?></label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Ubah Kata Sandi</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        </div>
```

[and my database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9vAd.png)

Comment: instead of <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Ubah Kata Sandi</button>, you can try once with <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Ubah Kata Sandi">

Comment: Yea, that make sense... why i use button tag when the class is btn. But its still not solve my problem .-.

Comment: Did you determine if  $id = $session->get('id'); was giving you the correct id? And I do not see where  $this-user is defined. What you can also do is examine what the Generated SQL is  by using echo $db->getLastQuery() and seeing and testing what it produces.

Comment: Yes, the id is correct. $this->user is get from protected $user, you can call like that. Okay, ill check about that getlastquery, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake, its work when i put my update password code into a new function...

Example:

```
Public function updatepassword(){
 $data['user'] = $model->UserLogin();

$pass_sebelum = $request->getPost('katasandi_sebelum');
                $pass_baru = $request->getPost('katasandi_baru');
                if (!password_verify($pass_sebelum, $data['user']['sandi'])) {
                    $this->session->setFlashdata('salah', 'Kata sandi sebelumnya salah!');
                    return redirect()->to(base_url('/pengguna/katasandi'));
                }else{
                    if ($pass_sebelum == $pass_baru) {
                        $this->session->setFlashdata('sama', 'Kata sandi baru tidak boleh sama dengan kata sandi sebelumnya!');
                        return redirect()->to(base_url('/pengguna/katasandi'));
                    }else{
                        $password_hash = password_hash($pass_baru, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                        $model->EditKataSandi($password_hash);
                        $this->session->setFlashdata('pesan', 'Kata sandi berhasil diubah!');
                        return redirect()->to(base_url('/pengguna/katasandi'));
                    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$allowedFields`.

This array should be updated with the field names that can be set during save, insert, or update methods. Any field names other than these will be discarded. This helps to protect against just taking input from a form and throwing it all at the model, resulting in potential mass assignment vulnerabilities. `protected $allowedFields = ['name', 'email'];`

You can read more in the official documentation: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html#models